# Undefined array after fetching data

Tags: reactjs, arrays, fetch

I have a problem, that I can't figure out. After fetching data to an array I can display this array, but I can't display just one object in it or map through it

```
useMemo(() => {
    // setTabIsLoading(true);
    console.log(tabIsLoading);
    const contentArray: Array<anime> = [];

    fetchingArray.map((animeId: string) => {
      const animeListHandler = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await fetch(
            `https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime/${animeId}`
          );
          if (response.ok) {
            const data = await response.json();
            const transformedData = {
              id: data.data.mal_id,
              name: data.data.title,
              image: data.data.images.jpg.large_image_url,
              description: data.data.synopsis,
              score: data.data.score,
            };

            contentArray.push(transformedData);
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
      };
      animeListHandler();
    });

    if (contentArray) {
      console.log(contentArray);
      console.log(contentArray[1]);
      const content = [];
      contentArray.map((anime) => {
        console.log(`anime: ${anime}`);
        content.push(<AnimePagesBox anime={anime} key={anime.id} />);
        return;
      });
      console.log(content);
      setActivePageContent(content);
      setTabIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, [activePage, tabIsLoading]);
```

that's the output of the code  (in cases of logging `contentArray` it shows full array with object):

```
true
Account.tsx:70 []
Account.tsx:71 undefined
Account.tsx:78 []
Account.tsx:41 false
Account.tsx:70 []
Account.tsx:71 undefined
Account.tsx:78 []
```

I also tried to add this array to an array in `useState`. Sometimes it worked, but still was an issue, that after getting to this page back I didn't see the output. So I don't even know, what to do
If I create a guard, that mapping starts only, when the length of the array is greater than 0, so it doesn't start

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Checkout [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). `fetchingArray.map` is finishing immediately, but the response from fetch will be available later, time travel is impossible. You have to wait for the map

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are facing an issue where you can't display individual objects from the contentArray.
The fetch function is **asynchronous**, and you are making multiple asynchronous requests inside the fetchingArray.map loop.
You can use `Promise.all` to wait for all requests to complete before processing the contentArray.

```
useMemo(() => {
  const contentArray: Array<anime> = [];

  const fetchAnimeData = async (animeId: string) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime/${animeId}`);
      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        const transformedData = {
          id: data.data.mal_id,
          name: data.data.title,
          image: data.data.images.jpg.large_image_url,
          description: data.data.synopsis,
          score: data.data.score,
        };
        contentArray.push(transformedData);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  const promises = fetchingArray?.map((animeId: string) => fetchAnimeData(animeId));

  Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    const content = contentArray?.map((anime) => {
      console.log(`anime: ${anime}`);
      return <AnimePagesBox anime={anime} key={anime.id} />;
    });
    console.log(content);
    setActivePageContent(content);
    setTabIsLoading(false);
  });
}, [activePage, tabIsLoading]);
```

Comment: See also: [Dealing with Promises In an Array with async/await](https://dev.to/afifsohaili/dealing-with-promises-in-an-array-with-async-await-5d7g) for more strategies.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl cool article!. Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, use `Promise.all`. It will return a promise containing the results of every promise passed into it. Also, you should not pass the entire `anime` object into the subcomponent. Try to pass primitive values if you can. If you look at the `<AnimeBox>` component below, you will see how props can be spread into the component.

Here is a runnable Stack Snippet demonstrating this:

**Note:** I switch from `async`/`await` to `Promise.then` in the snippet below, because the snippet's Babel version does not support the former.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const fetchAnimeData = (animeId) =>
  fetch(`https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime/${animeId}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((payload) => payload.data ? ({
        id: payload.data.mal_id,
        name: payload.data.title,
        image: payload.data.images.jpg.large_image_url,
        description: payload.data.synopsis,
        score: payload.data.score,
      }) : null);

const fetchMultiAnimeData = (...animeIds) =>
  Promise.all(animeIds.map(fetchAnimeData));

const AnimeBox = ({ id, name, image, description, score }) => {
  return (
    <div className="AnimeBox">
      <h2>{name} ({score}/10)</h2>
      <img height="128" src={image} />
      <p>{description}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [animeDataList, setAnimeDataList] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // ID 7 is invalid, and will not break rendering...
    fetchMultiAnimeData(1, 5, 6, 7).then(res => {
      // Filter out any null results
      setAnimeDataList(res.filter(v => v && v.id));
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <React.Fragment>
        {animeDataList.map(data => (
          <AnimeBox key={data.id} {...data} />
        ))}
      </React.Fragment>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```css
html, body, #root {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.App {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.AnimeBox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: thin solid grey;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.AnimeBox h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

## Update

Here is an updated example using `for async of` instead of `Promise.all`. It is written in TypeScript and uses Zod to validate the JSON response.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { z } from "zod";
import "./App.css";

type AnimeDetails = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  image: string;
  description: string;
  score: number;
};

const AnimeSchema = z.object({
  data: z.object({
    mal_id: z.number(),
    title: z.string(),
    images: z.object({
      jpg: z.object({
        large_image_url: z.string(),
      }),
    }),
    synopsis: z.string(),
    score: z.number(),
  }),
});

export type AnimeViewModel = z.infer<typeof AnimeSchema>;

async function fetchAnimeData(animeId: number): Promise<AnimeDetails | null> {
  const response = await fetch(`https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime/${animeId}`, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
  if (!response.ok) {
    return null;
  }
  const payload = await response.json();
  try {
    const anime: AnimeViewModel = AnimeSchema.parse(payload);
    return {
      id: anime!.data.mal_id,
      name: anime!.data.title,
      image: anime!.data.images.jpg.large_image_url,
      description: anime!.data.synopsis,
      score: anime!.data.score,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof z.ZodError) {
      console.error(err.issues);
    }
  }
  return null;
}

async function fetchMultiAnimeData(
  ...animeIds: number[]
): Promise<AnimeDetails[]> {
  const results: AnimeDetails[] = [];
  for await (const animeId of animeIds) {
    const anime = await fetchAnimeData(animeId);
    if (anime) {
      results.push(anime);
    }
  }
  return results;
}

type AnimeBoxProps = AnimeDetails;

function AnimeBox(props: AnimeBoxProps) {
  const { name, image, description, score } = props;
  return (
    <div className="AnimeBox">
      <h2>
        {name} ({score}/10)
      </h2>
      <img height="128" src={image} />
      <p>{description}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [animeDataList, setAnimeDataList] = useState<AnimeDetails[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMultiAnimeData(1, 5, 6, 7).then(setAnimeDataList);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <>
        {animeDataList.map((data) => (
          <AnimeBox key={data.id} {...data} />
        ))}
      </>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```